# How to query all the elements with this condition in the query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have the following models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    tags = models.ManyToMany(Tag, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have a list of `liked` suppliers and I would like to have all the tags this suppliers have. How can I get all the Tags contained in a list of suppliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__in`.

```
Tag.objects.filter(supplier__in=list_of_suppliers)
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: @Daniel_Roseman Thanks for the answer, what is the reason for it to work?, where can I find more info about this?